# Centre Buttons In Swift - Objective C Conversion Issue

Tags: objective-c, swift

In Objective C, I am using a function to centre some buttons, which works fine.
The buttons centre perfectly on the screen.
However, converting the code to swift it isn't working as expected. There is extra space on the left hand side:

```
func centerImageViews()

        // Measure the total width taken by the buttons
    var width:CGFloat = 0.0

    for (index, item) in enumerate(self.soundBoxes) {

        if(item.tag>=numberOfBoxes){
            item.alpha=0

        }else{
            item.alpha=1
            width += item.bounds.size.width + 10
        }

        if (width > 10){
        width -= 10;
        }

        // If the buttons width is shorter than the visible bounds, adjust origin
        var origin:CGFloat = 0;

        if (width < self.view.frame.size.width){

        origin = (self.view.frame.size.width - width) / 2.0;

        }

        // Place buttons
        var x:CGFloat = origin;
        var y:CGFloat = 200;

       for (index, item) in enumerate(self.soundBoxes) {

        item.center = CGPointMake(x + item.bounds.size.width/2.0, y + item.bounds.size.height/2.0);
        x += item.bounds.size.width + 10;

        }


    }
```

}

In Objective C:

```
- (void)centerImageViews:(NSArray*)imageViews withCount:(int)number 
{    
    int kButtonSeperator=10;

    // Measure The Total Width Of Our Buttons
    CGFloat width = 0;

    for (UIImageView* hit in soundBoxes)

        if (hit.tag>=numberOfBoxes) {
            hit.alpha=0;
        } else {
            width += hit.bounds.size.width + kButtonSeperator;
            hit.alpha=1;
        }


    if (width > kButtonSeperator)
        width -= kButtonSeperator;

    CGFloat origin = 0;

    if (width < self.view.frame.size.width)
        origin = (self.view.frame.size.width - width) / 2.f;

    CGFloat x = origin;
    CGFloat y = 85;

    UIImageView* hit;

    for (hit in imageViews) {
        hit.center = CGPointMake(x + hit.bounds.size.width/2.f, y + hit.bounds.size.height/2.f);

        //NSLog(@"X Is %f",hit.center.x);

        x += hit.bounds.size.width + kButtonSeperator;


    }

}


}
```

Comment: Whilst formatting you code for the `objective-c` part I noticed you had an extra closing brace `}` Where is the opening `{` brace for this?

Comment: I do apologize,this must have been typed in error.